# Custom validator based on Association value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My application has 3 Models (Foo, Bar and Baz)

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
  has_many   :bazs

class Baz
  belongs_to :bar
```

I'm trying to find the most intuitive way to validate a attribute in Baz (price), against limits set in Foo ( :min_price and :max_price ). Price in the Baz model must be between the limits set by Foo.

Currently I am trying to implement it using a custom PriceLimitValidator:

```
class PriceLimitValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless ( record.price <= record.bar.foo.max_price && record.price >= record.bar.foo.min_price )
      record.errors[:price] << 'Price limit exceeded!'
    end
  end
end
```

This results in a NilClass error and frankly doesn't feel like the simplest solution.

Any tips for a rails beginner?

Comment: show the full error stack..

Comment: Not related but `has_many   :baz` should be `has_many   :bazs`.. **plural**..

Comment: In which model you put the *custom validator* ? `max_price` and `min_price` are model attributes ?

Comment: Rails provides some validations based on the Ruby range capabilities right out of the box.  For instance,   validates_numericality_of :width, less_than: ->(person) { person.height }, :greater_than... etc. } http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_numericality_of

Comment: is it `record.price` or `record.price_amount` ?  You use both.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, It should be record.price. I have updated it. Thanks

Comment: @Valerie, I will test your solution and let you know. Looks viable

Comment: @herm, Hope it helps, if so I'd like to make it an answer. Will that work for you?

Comment: @Valerie, your solution worked. If you want, you can add an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Herm, I'm glad it was the widget that helped solve your problem. Posted as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails provides spiffy validations based on the Ruby range capabilities right out of the box.

For instance:

```
validates_numericality_of :width, less_than: ->(person) { person.height }, :greater_than... etc. }
```

The complete spec with its myriad options is here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_numericality_of

Answer (score 1):

Probably .bar or .bar.foo does not exist. I would implement it in this way:

```
class Foo
  validates_presence_of :min_price, :max_price
end

class Baz
  belongs_to :bar
  has_one :foo, through: :bar

  validates_presence_of :foo

  def min_price
    foo.try(:min_price)
  end

  def max_price
    foo.try(:min_price)
  end
end

class PriceLimitValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    return if record.min_price.nil? || record.max_price.nil?

    unless record.price.between?(record.min_price, record.max_price)
      record.errors[:price] << 'Price limit exceeded!' 
    end
  end
end
```

Check relation between Baz and Foo. It cannot be belongs_to, because belongs_to assume that foreign_key exists in the first model. In this case you have to define has_one :through.

I also have implemented min_price and max_price in the Baz model. It's a handy pattern that allows you to shorten method chaining. Also it allows your validator to check only this attributes without any knowledge about model association.

And what is the most important I validate presence of :foo and in PriceLimitValidator I check if min_price and max_price are defined. It is not the responsibility of this validator to check if related object exists.

Of course you can adapt this logic to your needs.